# UILabel with text constrainedToSize returns wrong height

Tags: ios, uilabel

I've read many questions on the topic but I can't seem to find what is wrong with my code:

```
UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[nameLabel setText: _nameString];

nameLabel.textAlignment    = UITextAlignmentLeft;
nameLabel.contentMode      = UIViewContentModeTop;
nameLabel.lineBreakMode    = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
nameLabel.numberOfLines    = 0;
nameLabel.font             = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:14];
nameLabel.backgroundColor  = [UIColor clearColor];
nameLabel.textColor        = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.282 blue:0.31 alpha:1];
nameLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

CGSize maximumLabelSize  = CGSizeMake(200.0f, 60.0f);
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [_nameString sizeWithFont:nameLabel.font
                                   constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize 
                                       lineBreakMode:nameLabel.lineBreakMode];

nameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, expectedLabelSize.width, expectedLabelSize.height);
```

And although sometimes it does work (on larger texts) on texts like "Airplanes being the future" the `expectedLabelSize` returns height 18.0f and it cuts the sentence on the "Airplanes being the"

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem once, that was because my label's width was smaller than the maximum Label's width wat I used to calculate the "expectedLabelSize".

Since you are using an autoresizingMask your label might be too small.